# When science and English overlap, who wins?

Tags: discussion

> Is there a good word for change in velocity, but not over time? That is, position is to displacement as velocity is to what?

[This old question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83449/word-for-change-in-velocity/83503#83503) (2012) came up in suggested results. While it is a single word request, I would consider it to be more physics-oriented than EL&U-oriented given the topic and its narrow usage.

While it's not hurting anything here on EL&U, should I flag it for migration? As one commenter remarked about the accepted answer,

> This is essentially a science question, not about language. See below:
>   Δv is a notation, not a word in the English language

And how should we handle such overlap in the future?

Comment: In re the question from 2012, I’d say let sleeping dogs lie. It’s sleeping there happy and warm under a 6-year deep pile of questions that have come after it. In re future questions: this isn’t exactly a pandemic problem. We can and should take them on a case by case basis.

Comment: That *question* is perfectly legitimate as something to do with the English language. Unfortunately, the accepted *answer* has nothing to do with the English language.

Answer (score 4):

A few things:

1. If it's older than 60 days old, it can't even be migrated by a diamond moderator (see [Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/323179)). You'd need a Stack Exchange employee (i.e. a CM), and they won't do this except in very special conditions (e.g. a site closing down). If you flag the post, your flag is likely to be declined.
2. If it's on topic here, it shouldn't be closed.
3. If you're not familiar with a site, don't suggest people move questions there. In far too many cases, I've seen people be wrong with their suggestions. I've never posted on Physics, but from what I read on their meta, [most questions about terminology are off-topic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083), so I doubt this one would be on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

By 'English', in contrast to 'science', I expect you mean informal language as opposed to formal, stipulated, technical language. If the technical meaning is not requested, then it is totally on-topic and  **both meanings are appropriate to discuss here**.

Of course, a **question about stipulated technical meaning** will get more accurate answers on a specialty website, and a suggestion as such is an appropriate comment and ***may*** **be reason for migration**, but it is not a necessary thing. But the answers here will certainly be better at the in the informal or OED-style meanings rather than giving a technical definition.